# What determines when 'bot.dialog' passes to the next function of the waterfall in Microsoft Bot Framework? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, botframework

I'm working with Microsoft Bot Framework v3 in a company that has built a huge library on top of it.  Their library is not documented, and it's hard for me to know when in `bot.dialog` you pass on to the next function of the waterfall 'automatically' and when you need to call next.

In the MS Bot Framework, things like `builder.Prompts.text` will pass the results on to the next function in the waterfall automatically, without having to call `next`.  For example [image]

Is there something somewhere down in the MS Bot Framework original code that gets called every time the waterfall passes on to the next function?  Then perhaps I could put a trace statement on that code and see which functions of their library call that and then trigger the transition automatically, without me having to call `next` explicitly.

Thanks for any help -- I'm aware that this function seems quite vague, but it's simply that I'm left on my own to understand their library, without documentation, and I'm unclear how their functions work (in contrast I understand how the original MS Bot Framework functions work, because there is documentation).

Comment: I'm a little confused by this because it sounds like you're asking how the Bot Framework functions work despite saying you already understand how the Bot Framework functions work and despite the SDK being [open source](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/tree/master/Node). Can you clarify what specifically you want us to look up for you?

Comment: @KyleDelaney -- Fair enough.  When I say I understand how it works, what I mean is that I've read through the documentation a week ago and understand at a basic level, and I've gone through some of the source.  I accept that it's probably on me to go through the source code and figure out how the steps are processed, but if anyone can point me in the right direction, so much the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't count the pseudo-waterfalls created by [`WaterfallDialog.createHandler`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/blob/master/Node/core/src/dialogs/WaterfallDialog.ts#L144-L198), the only place the waterfall step counter gets incremented is in [`WaterfallDialog.dialogResumed`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/blob/master/Node/core/src/dialogs/WaterfallDialog.ts#L70-L85), and that's only when the resume reason is not `reprompt` or `back`:

```typescript
public dialogResumed(session: Session, result: IDialogResult<any>): void {
    let step = session.dialogData[consts.Data.WaterfallStep];
    switch (result.resumed) {
        case ResumeReason.reprompt:
            // Ignore re-prompts
            return;
        case ResumeReason.back:
            step--;
            break;
        default:
            step++;
            break;

    }
    this.doStep(session, step, result);
}
```

When you talk about calling `next`, I presume you mean `skip`. It's worth noting that `skip` itself calls `dialogResumed`:

```typescript
var skip = (result?: IDialogResult<any>) => {
    result = result || <any>{};
    if (result.resumed == null) {
        result.resumed = ResumeReason.forward;
    }
    this.dialogResumed(session, result);
};
```

Apart from that, `dialogResumed` will only be called when a dialog on top of the waterfall dialog ends, so you're supposed to include prompts in your waterfall steps if you want the waterfall to advance automatically on subsequent steps.

Since you mentioned wanting to use some kind of trace statement, there's no obvious place to put a trace statement in your own code that would execute whenever the waterfall advances to the next step. However, you could use [`WaterfallDialog.onBeforeStep`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/blob/master/Node/core/src/dialogs/WaterfallDialog.ts#L87-L90) to include a [`BeforeWaterfallStepHandler`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/blob/master/Node/core/src/dialogs/WaterfallDialog.ts#L43) that executes before any step is processed, whether it's the next step or not:

```typescript
export type BeforeWaterfallStepHandler = (session: Session, step: number, args: any, next: (step: number, args: any) => void) => void;
```

Notice that a `BeforeWaterfallStepHandler` does include a `next` parameter, but calling it just proceeds to the next handler rather than the next waterfall step (though you could call it with an incremented `step` value).

Please remember that the v3 SDK is deprecated and everyone is encouraged to migrate to v4 as soon as possible. It will become increasingly difficult for you to get any help with v3.